# How can i get constituents of a member function from its address?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to get the constituents of a member function such as class type or return type just from its address (not from member function type) ?

For e.g. given

```
 class foo
 {
    int bar()
    {
        return 5;
    }
 };
```

i like to have

```
is_same< function_types<&foo::bar>::class_type, foo>::value == true;
```

I also know additionally that the member function has a signature like `R (C::*)()` i.e no arguments and no cv-qualification.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "constituents?"  Do you mean you want to know the function's signature?

Comment: Can you provide realistic example that makes sense? In your case you know that bar is a member function of foo, because you take its address.

Comment: What do you mean, "not from member function type"? If you're using `&foo::bar` in your code, then the compiler does have the type.

Comment: Even if you only had an `int Foo::*()` address, you'd still have all "constituent" types. There's no "naked" value that loses the type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ pre-0x, you can't do this very easily. In C++0x, you can use a combination of template functions and decltype to do this:

```
template <typename R> struct unary_function_info { typedef R result_type; typedef void class_type; };
template <typename R> unary_function_info get_function_info(R (*)());

template <typename C, typename R> struct unary_member_function_info { typedef R result_type; typedef C class_type; };
template <typename C, typename R> unary_member_function_info get_function_info(R (C::*)());

is_same<decltype(get_function_info(&foo::bar))::class_type, foo>::value == true;
```

And then expand the above out for as high an arity as you need.

Comment: decltype is the key here, which i do not have in current language. I was looking for if a simplified version of BOOST_TYPEOF can work without any registration of unknown types

Comment: @toton, you and me both :). I've done this recently and had to resort to a ton of template functions to get it to work. It's a giant PITA.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the type in a template function:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo() { std::cout << "OK\n"; }
    int bar() {return 0;}
};

template<typename C, typename R>
bool thing(R (C::*)()) {
    C x;
}

int main() {
    thing(&foo::bar);
}
```

prints "OK", so you could put your `is_same` check in there. I'm really not sure what the question is, though - obviously here we *are* using the type of the member function for template argument deduction.

If you've somehow invalidly `reinterpret_cast` a member function pointer to something else, so as to discard its type, then no you can't recover it.

If you've converted your member function pointer to a compatible member function pointer type, for example `R (B::*)()` -> `R (D::*)()`, where B is a base class of D, then I think you can use `dynamic_cast` to test whether it really is a B function after all. You can't recover the type that way, just the `typeid` of the member function pointer, because it's a runtime operation. Types really only exist at compile-time in C++, so there's no way to "get" the dynamic type of a value, whether that value is a member function pointer or anything else. The compiler either knows it, or it doesn't, and if it does then there's various template trickery to actually *use* the constituents of that type.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. This is part of what is called **run-time reflection** and is not possible in such low-level language as C++. You cannot get this data from only the address.

*Whatever you're doing, in C++ you're likely to be able to do this with a metaprogramming approach, using template magic or preprocessor magic. For example, Boost libraries rely on such approach.*

Comment: That’s false. C++ offers *abundant* “compile-time reflection” in the form of template metafunctions (“traits”). What C++ is bad at is *runtime* reflection. Furthermore, this isn’t “only the address” – it’s a *strongly-typed* address.

Comment: Yup, a typo by me - I meant `runtime refkection`, as the OP stated "just from its address, not from member function type"). Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use overloading:

```
void F(int);
void F(bool);


F(foo.bar());
```

You can use template functions and partial specialisation for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct char2_t { char xxx[2]; };

template <bool flag, typename T, typename U> struct select   { typedef T type; }; 
template <typename T, typename U> struct select<false, T, U> { typedef U type; }; 

template<class Foo, class C, class R>
typename select<boost::is_same<Foo, C>::value, char, char2_t>::type test(R (C::*)());


void check_in_this_function() {
 char check_arr1[ sizeof(test<foo>(&foo::bar))==1 ? 1 : -1]; 
 char check_arr2[ sizeof(test<int>(&foo::bar))==1 ? 1 : -1];  // error: negative subscript
}
```

Comment: This of course assumes that you've got a finite set of candidates (`foo` and `int`).

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you are passing around a member function pointer as a simple type, you can get the constituent parts with something like the following. (This requires C++0x, in current C++ making it support arbitrary arities would take a lot more work.)

```
#include <tuple>

template <class T>
struct method_traits;

template <class ReturnType, class ObjectType, class... ArgTypes>
struct method_traits<ReturnType (ObjectType::*)(ArgTypes...)>
{
    typedef ReturnType result_type;
    typedef ObjectType object_type;
    template <unsigned N>
    struct argument
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<N - 1, std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>::type type;
    };
};

template <class ReturnType, class ObjectType, class... ArgTypes>
struct method_traits<ReturnType (ObjectType::*)(ArgTypes...) const>
{
    typedef ReturnType result_type;
    typedef ObjectType object_type;
    template <unsigned N>
    struct argument
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<N - 1, std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>::type type;
    };
};

struct Foo
{
    int bar(double, float) const ;
};

template <class MemberFun>
void test(MemberFun f)
{
    typename method_traits<MemberFun>::result_type result;
    typename method_traits<MemberFun>::object_type object;
    typename method_traits<MemberFun>::template argument<1>::type i = 10;  //:)
    result = (object.*f)(i, 2.0f);
}

int main()
{
    test(&Foo::bar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for it. However to capture the result_type like  test<&foo::bar>::result_type i need decltype.I may not need the variadic templates as i don't need that generic case of unknown number of arguments. I was looking for an implementation in current language in line of BOOST_TYPEOF with hope that it can be simplified given it is known in prior that type is a member function with no argument.

Comment: @toton: In this case you could just remove the variadic macro stuff which is there only for arities. I don't see why you should need `decltype`, because one way or another, you must already have the type of the pointer, and therefore you can instantiate `method_traits` and retrieve the result type.